# Best practices for Server safe expanding the functionality, depending on version of the Mobile app

Tags: java, android, algorithm, mobile

what I have:

- a mobile app, that checks the current version of an application after each auth and shows a special dialog box with some info - `a new version of software is available` or `you can't use the application before it willn't be updated`. But this functional is not available for all users.
- a server that handles any request from the mobile app (e.g. serching by criteria) and responses to a client

what I need:

- after adding a new functional to the app, it shouldn't be available for old versions (e.g. the current app version is `1.1.1` and new modifications are used only since the app has version `1.1.2`). Modifications can be variety.

what I can:

- make a force updating all clients that have the old version of the app and coerce all users to update the app after new modifications will have been made by regular updates (e.g. once a  month).
- create a table `Filter`, add types of modifications, modifications, and special params and modify functions by the values from the table `Filter`.
  All of these ways seems to me like a dirty hack.

**I want to know is there any way to do this better. Has anyone faced with such problems and have a good idea to resolve it better? Thanks.**

Comment: I don't understand. You have a web app that should behave differently based on the version of an android client app? Just have multiple versions of it and like http://url.com/v1.1.1/index.html etc?

Comment: @zapl, I have the server without web part, it only handles android requests(auth, search, get extra info etc) and responses to clients. And some new modifications of the server or mobile app should be available only for the new version of software(e.g. new fields  were added to the request/response etc). Client's app version I get via authentication and store to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `force to update` is not very nice aproach, but if you really need it, you can put `User-Agent` header in all your requests to server and create a filter there (on the server), which will return specific error to all the requests made with app version less than the version you want. Then in the app you can handle this specific error and show so called `screen of death`.

Also you can version `API`. Say you added new fields in the response of `/users` endpoint. So `v1.1.1` can do calls to `/v1/users` and `v1.1.2` can work with `/v2/users`.

In general idea is that client app is very light and it is up to server to decide what and how to return.

Comment: But there are clients with old versions of the app, and they have not special functionality to show screen of death. 
Yes, I can add new spring controller like `/v2/users` but doesn't it increase the code duplicating? Because e.g. I should modify a function in the deep bowels of my app.

Comment: how to do API versioning is a different topic, there are different ways to do it. For the old apps without "screen-of-death" support functionality I doubt you can do anything. The problem is that you need to let the users know that they can/should update the app, so you need to have a communication channel to do it. Maybe you can send them push message.

Comment: I thought about push messages, but this offer was refused. I've edit my question. The main goal in this case to force the server to add new functionality for different versions of apllication.